# KeyListener not fireing in JApplet

Tags: java, swing, japplet

Nothing happens when I type, press, nor release a key. I'm Trying to add keylistener using this keyword.  When I add a mouse listener it works just fine.

```
class MainApplet extends JApplet implements KeyListener{

MainApplet(){ addKeyListener(this) }

public void init(){}

public void start(){}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.print(e);

}
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Answer (score 4):

KeyEvents are only generated for the component that has focus. No component on your applet has focus, so not components can receive KeyEvents.

Try something like:

```
Component contentPane = getContentPane();
contentPane.setFocusable(true);
contentPane.addKeyListener( this );
```

The real question is what are you trying to do? There is probably a better solution that we can suggest when we know the real requirement. Normally you would use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) to listen for a KeyStroke on a given component.

Comment: I know key bindings are coming so I'll just give you +1 now ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer, we are getting too predictable :)